# On deploying latest Aspose 10.6.2 v getting NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION on save in UNIX env

Tags: aspose.pdf

I had migrated the jar to Aspose latest version(10.6.2) and successfully deployed on UNIX env. While saving the form in UNIX env I am getting  NullpointerPointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Tilal Ahmad and I am a developer evangelist at Aspose.

Please note on non-windows OSs subjected exception arises due to font folder path setting. You need to set font folder path according to your machine setting before using any other code, it will resolve the issue. For example on my Ubuntu server, I set font folder path as following.

```
// Set font folder path
String path = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/";
// Adding a single font directory
// com.aspose.pdf.Document.addLocalFontPath(path);

// seting the user list for standard font directories
java.util.List list = com.aspose.pdf.Document.getLocalFontPaths();
list.add(path);

com.aspose.pdf.Document.setLocalFontPaths(list);

.....
.....
```